# Endpoint login - spring security

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, bcrypt, endpoint

I want create endpoint login with using spring security (basic authentication).
What I want? If you provide correct data, response will be 200 or 202 and when bad data response will be HTTP 400.

Controller

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/login")
public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestParam String login) {
    try {
        Client client= clientService.findOneByLogin(login);
        if(client.getRole().equals("USER"))
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(JSONObject.quote(client.getRole()),HttpStatus.OK);
        else if(client.getRole().equals("ADMIN"))
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(JSONObject.quote(client.getRole()),HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        else
            throw new Exception();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

Configuration Spring Security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/reg/login").hasAnyAuthority("USER","ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/reg/register").permitAll()
            .and().httpBasic()
            .and().csrf().disable();        
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}}
```

UserDetailService

```
 @Service()
    public class ClientDetailService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        try {
            Client client = clientRepository.findByLogin(login);

            Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(client.getRole()));

            if (client == null)
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user in database with login " + login);
            else if (!client.getActive())
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No active user with login " + login);
            else {
                return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(client.getLogin(), client.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }}
```

Now if I provide first bad password, all is ok, in response is HTTP 401. But if first good data, and then other (bad), all time in response is 200 or 202.

Who will tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Why `@Service()`? isn't it `@Service`? And which url you used for login ? your ant matcher said if you are going to login with `reg/login` then you must have any authority `"USER","ADMIN"`. Din't sure which url you used and before login, how can you validate authority for user ?

Comment: For 'login' I used `/reg/login` (`/reg` is above controller class). I want if I don't authority return something exception, that the body of method controller should't be performed.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me, what is the right way? Even if I tested this endpoint in postman, I had a problem about which spoke earlier.

Comment: I found solution already. The problem was a session, which was created by spring security. It was enough add to configuration security: `sessionManagement()
.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)`